# Where is MySQL dump file?

Tags: mysql

I have used the MySQL mysqldump command. It said "dump complete". Where can I now find the file which contains the MySQL statments?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually you use this command from the command line and pipe the output to a file:

```
mysqldump db_name > backup-file.sql
```

Then the dump will be in the file `backup-file.sql` in the current directory. If you don't redirect then the output will just be displayed to the screen, not saved to a file.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. But now I get "Access is denied"

Comment: @nix: It looks like you don't have permission to write to that file/directory. Try writing to another location.

Comment: You can use `--result-file`
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file

Comment: You can learn the path of the backup file with `pwd`. Because it stays your current directory...